# How to randomly generate numbers from 3000 to 80000 ending with zeros only?

Tags: php

I would like to randomly generate numbers like:

3000 4000 5000 etc... between 3000 and 80000.

How might I do that?

Comment: Generate numbers from 3 to 80, multiply by 1000, round, done

Comment: Is 11000 allowed, or just 8000, 9000, 10000, 20000, 30000, ...?

Comment: @Pekka: I hope you don't mind I just used it in my answer

Comment: Do you want the sequence that only has a single leading nonzero digit (...8000, 9000, 10000, 20000, ...) or do you want the multiples-of-a-thousand sequence that has two non-zero leading digits above 10000 (...8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo $your_number = (rand(3,80) * 1000);
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/07566)

Comment: Can anybody explain his/her downvote, so I can improve my answer?

Comment: Do you need a round() call in that first one?  It doesn't look like it's doing anything, since rand(3,80) is already an integer.

Comment: @BrooksMoses: I don't. Edited

Comment: The downvote likely occured when you only had your "worse" answer up.  That one is indeed worthy of downvote; it creates a completely unnecessary array.

Comment: @BrooksMoses: Okay, deleted that one. Thanks for info

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:

```
$number = rand(3,80)*1000;
```

you can test with this

```
for ($index = 0; $index < 20; $index++) {
     echo (rand(3,80)*1000)."<br />";
}
```